# Condition Clause in AWS Policy Statement Behavior between ListObjects and ListObjectsV2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

After upgrading Terraform from v1.5.x to v1.6.x, our pipeline started to fail. Looking at the debug logs, it turned out that at the beginning, Terraform makes a *list-objects* call which is `ListObjects` in 1.5.x and `ListObjectsV2` in 1.6.x (in AWS GO SDK V1 vs V2). Now the exact error was the famous "Access Denied" when calling `ListObjectsV2`, whereas, surprisingly, the older version (calling `ListObjects`) used to work just fine.
Looking at the policy attached to the Terraform Backend AWS role, we suspected that the `Condition` clause could be the issue:

```json
{
  "PolicyName": "StateBucketPolicy",
  "PolicyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::state-bucket-123456789012",
        "Condition": {
          "StringLike": { "s3:prefix": [ "states/${aws:PrincipalTag/Repository}/123456789012/*" ] }
        }
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["s3:DeleteObject", "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject"],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::state-bucket-123456789012/states/${aws:PrincipalTag/Repository}/123456789012/*"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After removing the `Condition` clause, it started working again.
Interestingly we realized that the `Condition` clause was wrong all along; it should have been `[ "env:/*" ]`.

Now my question is why the policy works in the older version (calling `ListObjects`) despite the `Condition` clause being wrong. (I checked the debug logs in the old version and it's still calling with `env:/` as the prefix). Does `ListObjects` get authorized differently? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks.